# Is there any solution to upgrade an app with new keystore

Tags: android, google-play

We want to update an existing Application but unfortunately we have a problem. Our keystore to sign up the app is not the same as the one we used in the previous version of the application. Therefore we can´t upgrade our existing app in the market. Is there any way to get the old key (certificate) from our previous version which is currently in the market place?

Is there any solution to upgrade our existing version with the new one we would like to publish in the store?
What happens to the users who have installed the current version if we delete this version in the marketplace and upload a the new version (with the same name)?
Do they get an update notification or do they have to install the new app?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/bin/request.py?contact_type=contact_policy&policy=apps

I would email the Android Market guys, they have provided fixes for people before, they have moved whole apps over to a new account for people, so they may be able to help you with your issue. If not the post above is the best explanation, either new app and they will have to download or try to find the old keystore.. sorry man.. hopefully they can help

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I found no contact email listed - do you know a way to contact the support for Android Market directly? thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?answer=136601&hl=en

on that link, if you scroll down there is a link to click on "Publishing Issues" 

which takes you here
http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/request.py?&contact_type=publishing

fill out the forum and your good to go.. :)

Answer (score 5):

You must use the previously used certificate to sign your app if you want to upload an updated version to the market.  If you use a new certificate to sign your app and try to upload it as a new version, it will fail.  If you upload it as a new application, the existing users will not be informed of the update.

Edit - if you have your Keystore but forgot the alias, you can [try to recover it](http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/listing-aliases-inside-an-android-keystore-file-with-keytool/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as what I know Its **not possible to recover the same keystore** anyhow , so you cant upgrade the existing Application. The only solution is you have to launch a complete new app.